# Using IntelliJ-Idea - Getting "Cannot Resolve Symbol" on Spinners

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-spinner

So I'm using the android guide for creating a spinner and I can create both the spinner and ArrayAdapter objects but the .setDropDownViewResource(int i) and .setAdapter(adapter a) methods say they cannot be resolved ("cannot resolve symbol")

```
package com.example.testframework;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.crop_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.crop_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(17367049);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }

    public void onNothingClicked(AdapterView<?> parent){
        parent.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    }
```

Comment: What is `SendData` and why you declared the `Spinner` and `ArrayAdapter` outside the class?

Comment: Look at the revised code, that code was a remnant from a previous code attempt I hadn't yet picked out (thanks for noticing it!)

Comment: The revised code is worse :) Where is the class name? Where have you defined the class/activity name? Look at this [`Android Spinner (Drop Down List) Example`](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)

Comment: This is just a small portion of the larger class which is really chunky, the main class declairation is: public class SendData extends ListActivity{. I looked at that example earlier and my class implements everything the same way without the expected result

Comment: Have you checked the JDK and Android SDK installations? `File`>`Project Structure`>`Platform Settings`>`SDKs`

Comment: I'm using the 4.2.2 android sdk with Java 1.6 (1.7 isn't needed). I also get an "Unknown class error" when I put android.R.layot.simple_spinner_dropdown_item in the setDropDownViewResource as it normally is in the [Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener)

Comment: Have you compiled any other app with this IntelliJ installation?

Comment: Yes, the basic application that they have on the android page, written by hand with the same settings.

Comment: One last thing that I can guess. What is the Project SDK set to? `File`>`Project Structure`>`Project Setting`>`Project`>`Project SDK`?

Comment: Nothing left in my small mind. If you use repository, I can take a look at your code to see if something missing. Otherwise I think you should wait for someone knowledgeable.

Comment: thanks for the help, at least we ruled some things out!

Comment: NP. Hope you get it working soon ;)

Answer (score 4):

u shud add it inside `onCreate()` method , else it will not work, for example

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner          layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

   }
```